# Send-mailmessage failing because attachment is missing (messed up variable)

Tags: variables, powershell

I am sending a bunch of files as attachments with `Send-MailMessage`
Some of the files exist, some do not, hence `Send-MailMessage` fails if one of the files is missing.

Is there a way I can do a `Test-Path` and clean up `$attachments` if a file is missing?

My code:

```
$Attachments = "$longlist_file","$PingList_File","$quicklist_file", `
  "$nConf_import_host_file","$nConf_import_service_file", `
  "$nconf_export_host_file","$nconf_export_service_file"

# Sending mail
send-mailmessage -to $ToAddress -from $FromAddress -smtpserver $SMTPServer `
  -subject $MessageSubject -Body $MessageBody -Attachments $Attachments
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably

```
$Attachments = $longlist_file","$PingList_File","$quicklist_file", `
  "$nConf_import_host_file", "$nConf_import_service_file", `
  "$nconf_export_host_file", "$nconf_export_service_file" `
  | Where-Object { Test-Path $_ }
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you all for your help. I voted selected this as an answer because of how short and compact it is.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new list with only the files that exist:

```
$realFiles = $Attachments | ? {Test-Path -Path $_}
```

Then send.

```
send-mailmessage -to $ToAddress -from $FromAddress -smtpserver $SMTPServer -subject $MessageSubject -Body $MessageBody -Attachments $realFiles
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
$Attachments = @("$longlist_file","$PingList_File","$quicklist_file","$nConf_import_host_file","$nConf_import_service_file","$nconf_export_host_file","$nconf_export_service_file")
$TestedAttachments = @()
foreach($file in $Attachments)
{
    try
    {
        $file = get-content -path $file
        write-host "File $($file) exists, adding to tested list"
        $TestedAttachments += $file
    }
    catch[system. exception]
    {
        write-host "File $(file) was not found."
    }
}
send-mailmessage -to $ToAddress -from $FromAddress -smtpserver $SMTPServer -subject $MessageSubject -Body $MessageBody -Attachments $TestedAttachments
```

regards
Arcass

Comment: Reading the file is unnecessary when you just want to test if it exists. You can use the `Test-Path` cmdlet to verify a file exists instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
get-childitem $attachments -ea 0 | send-mailmessage......
```